# add some text after currency symbol in site

Tags: price

we can see price in site as : $699.99

I want to change $699.99 to $. 699.9

i want to put "dOT" and "space" after $ symbol.

please help me to find solution

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the currency symbol in adminpanel itself.

> Admin > System > Manage Currency > Symbols

Then you can change the currency symbol. The currency symbol will change everywhere.

Comment: I need to show after price. Ex: $120 USD

Comment: How to do this on Magento 2?