# Magento 2 : Add custom text after price amount show

Tags: magento2, checkout, price, mini-cart

I am trying to add **custom** **text** after **price** display **everywhere**(globally) in website.

1. category view
2. product view
3. Mini cart
4. cart page
5. checkout page
   etc..

can anyone help to me...

Comment: It will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74339/add-some-text-after-currency-symbol-in-site

Answer (score 0):

Please try to override `Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml` from core vendor to your theme path and added the text in the above or after rendering price.

Comment: Yes, but it will only change in product view page .I need everywhere in cart checkout etc...

Answer (score 0):

**This for list page :**

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
  config: {
    mixins: {
      'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box': {
        'Vendor_Module/js/price-box-mixin': true
      }
    }
  }
};
```

`var/www/html/olystudio/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js`

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {

  return function (widget) {
    var globalOptions = {
      productId: null,
      priceConfig: null,
      prices: {},
      priceTemplate: '<span class="price"><%- data.formatted %>/ custom-text</span>'
    };

    $.widget('mage.priceBox', widget, {
      options: globalOptions
    });
    return $.mage.priceBox;
  }
});
```

**Checkout Cart and Summary page :**

https://webkul.com/blog/display-custom-price-fee-checkout-cart-summary-total-magento2/

I hope its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly! To add custom text after the price display globally throughout your Magento website, you'll need to make some modifications to your theme files. Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. Backup Your Files:** Before making any changes, it's always a good idea to create a backup of your theme files and database.
2. Edit Theme Files:** Navigate to your active theme directory in the Magento installation. The path is usually `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/`.
3. Locate Price Templates:** Inside your theme directory, look for the template files responsible for rendering prices. The most common files are:

   - `template/catalog/product/price.phtml` (for product view)
   - `template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` (for mini cart)
   - `template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` (for cart page)
   - `template/checkout/cart/totals/default.phtml` (for cart and checkout totals)
4. Edit Template Files:** Open the relevant template files in a code editor.
5. Find Price Display Code:** Search for the code responsible for displaying the price. This code will vary based on your theme and version but is usually something like `<?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>`.
6. Add Custom Text:** Just after the price display code, add your custom text. For example:

   ```php
   <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
   <span class="custom-text">Custom Text Here</span>
   ```
7. Apply to Other Templates:** Repeat steps 3-6 for other template files where you want to display the custom text after the price.
8. CSS Styling:** If needed, style the `custom-text` class using CSS to make it visually appealing.
9. Clear Cache:** Clear the Magento cache to see the changes take effect.

Please note that the exact code and files may vary based on your Magento version, theme, and customizations.